# Threading deadlock in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I'm getting a deadlock in python. I have a threading.Lock() global variable: `lock`

This code runs in the constructor of a class in one file with a condition variable: `self.worker_condition = threading.Condition(lock=lock)` (the global lock)

```
lock.acquire()
alive_tcp_connections[worker_port] = False
self.tcp_thread.start()
print("waiting on cv")
with self.worker_condition:
            while alive_tcp_connections[worker_port]:
                self.worker_condition.wait()
print("worker woke up")
lock.release()
```

This is the function that tcp_thread runs:

```
while True:
        # this will listen on this socket and return a json of what it captures
        if node_type == "worker":
            lock.acquire()
            print(node_type, " TCP Listener started")
            alive_tcp_connections[port] = True
            cv.notify()
            lock.release()
```

The issue is that the last print statement is "waiting on CV", the tcp_thread code does not run and hangs on the lock, the constructor code (the first one) hangs on the `wait()`

What could be causing the deadlock?

Comment: I haven't used locks as you have here, but I worry when I see `lock.acquire()` and `lock.release()` within the `tcp_thread` worker loop, but only `lock.acquire()` in the constructor code, without a corresponding `lock.release()`.   Is the release taken care of elsewhere?

Comment: yes sorry i cut off the code before that.

Comment: I would say you are blocked at the tcp_thread `lock.acquire()`, because your other thread has acquired the lock and not released it prior to entering its loop.

Comment: Yes, it seems like the condition variable is not releasing the lock, the documentation for threading objects says that the cv should release the lock when wait() is called. At this pointt he tcp_thread should run, but this does not seem to be the case

Comment: That would certainly make sense that you could not call wait within a locked region.

Comment: I think you are not referencing your sync variables correctly.  Are `lock`, `cv`, and `self.worker_condition` all referencing the same object?  By the documentation, they should be, to be able to use `wait` and `notify`.

Comment: Can you clarify what this code is supposed to do logically? You seem to hold the very condition you are waiting for, while also holding the underlying lock. That appears like three different meanings for a single flag.

Answer (score 0):

You're code runs as expected. You have a single global lock. You acquire the lock in the parent thread then call the child thread. The child tries to acquire the lock but fails because the parent already has the lock.

The parent should not be acquiring the lock. Or you can use a separate lock for the child.

Comment: the parent thread will release the lock when it calls  `self.worker_condition.wait()`, which should allow the child thread to run, unless this is not the expected behavior?

Comment: I think condition unable to aquire the lock, cuz it's already aquired .

Answer (score 0):

Double check condition objects docs:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#condition-objects

You have objects: `lock`, `cv` and `self.worker_condition` references which need to refer to the same condition object for `wait` and `notify` to work.

(At least that's how I read it)